# IText7 HtmltoPdf - Section/Page missing with HtmlConverter.convertToDocument

Tags: itext, itext7

In a java project, I am converting a FTL template to HTML. I then convert the HTML to PDF using Itext (7).
The html has 6 sections (logical). (e.g. 6x `<div class="someclass"></div>`). I tested out the html in some tools to check closing div tags etc. Seems fine.
When I use
`HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(msg, new FileOutputStream(strFullOutputPath),converterProperties);`

It works perfectly and the html is converted properly to PDF. (some stray errors about RGB colors amd css selectors, etc)

I needed to add footer and header so I followed the example at:
https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/pdfhtml-header-and-footer-examples

```
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(strFullOutputPath);    
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
HtmlConverter.convertToDocument(msg, pdfDocument, converterProperties);
```

Now the pdf is generated with header and footer, but somehow the last section is missing.
I have tried commenting out the EventHandlers - but still the last section is missing

```
//pdfDocument.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE, headerHandler);
//pdfDocument.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, footerHandler);

HtmlConverter.convertToDocument(msg, pdfDocument, converterProperties);
//footerHandler.writeTotal(pdfDocument);
pdfDocument.close();
```

The header is a simple text,and the footer is a Page numbering with style "Page x of Y".

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Interestingly enough, if I use ```HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(msg, pdfDocument,converterProperties); ``` all the sections are present in the output pdf. But ```footerHandler.writeTotal(pdfDocument) would not work. As the total number of pages is calculated after the pdf is created

Comment: Hi, can you attach your minimal reproducible code example and the HTML file you are using for conversion? It would be good if you also add a screenshot and outline the part that does not work as expected and describe the expected result